# Is it possible to access 64 bit machine from 32 bit machine?

Tags: windows

Is it possible to access and work on 64 bit windows/linux machine from 32 bit windows machine?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified what you want to access/work on, but in principle, **yes**.

In all but the most obscure cases, communication between devices does not depend on the underlying processor architecture.

There may be issues with applications running on either system - for example memory addressing limitations on 32-bit systems, or applications not being compatible (most 32-bit applications will run on 64-bit platforms, but not vice versa).

As an example, a 32-bit MySQL client can communicate with a 64-bit MySQL server, but will not be able to handle datasets over 3GB (not very plausible but you get the idea).

Answer (score 1):

To further clarify what @craig Watson said.

By "Access and Work on": I understand you mean to use remote desktop or VNC to remotely work on the destination 64bit machine, from a 32bit machine.

A 32bit Windows machine can be used to remotely log into a 64bit PC (doesnt matter if its windows or linux). Tools used to do so are things like RDP, or VNC.

For a use case like this the answer will always be yes. Effectively this as good as sitting on the remotely connected PC.

So YES you can.